# Error: Create an empty array list to hold the connections (Connection Pooling)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I want to implement Connection Pooling(Mysql Database) In my project.
I got the same sample code link : [Click here](http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2014/03/connection-pool-in-java-jdbc.html)

- I have created 3 classes
- **Configuration** class that holds Database Configuration
- **JdbcConnectionPool** class that Creating and managing the connections
- **DataSource** class to get connection and returning the connection to connection pool

[image]

In **JdbcConnectionPool.class** I am getting an error in line:

```
List<connection> availableConnections = new ArrayList<connection>();
```

The error says create class **"connection"** in package com.java.abc

My **JdbcConnectionPool.class**

```
package com.java.abc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class JdbcConnectionPool {

 List<connection> availableConnections = new ArrayList<connection>();

 public JdbcConnectionPool()
 {
  initializeConnectionPool();
 }

 private void initializeConnectionPool()
 {
  while(!checkIfConnectionPoolIsFull())
  {
   availableConnections.add(createNewConnectionForPool());
  }
 }

 private synchronized boolean checkIfConnectionPoolIsFull()
 {
  final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = Configuration.getInstance().DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS;

  if(availableConnections.size() < MAX_POOL_SIZE)
  {
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 //Creating a connection
 private Connection createNewConnectionForPool()
 {
  Configuration config = Configuration.getInstance();
  try {
   Class.forName(config.DB_DRIVER);
   Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
     config.DB_URL, config.DB_USER_NAME, config.DB_PASSWORD);
   return connection;
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;

 }

 public synchronized Connection getConnectionFromPool()
 {
  Connection connection = null;
  if(availableConnections.size() > 0)
  {
   connection = (Connection) availableConnections.get(0);
   availableConnections.remove(0);
  }
  return connection;
 }

 public synchronized void returnConnectionToPool(Connection connection)
 {
  availableConnections.add(connection);
 }
}
```

How can I fix this Error.?

Comment: `connection` or `Connection`? Please always post the **exact** error messages you get.

Comment: it's  connection.

Comment: And what is `connection`? Where does it come from?

Comment: That is what I am not able to understand 

`List<connection> availableConnections = new ArrayList<connection>();`

In this Line I am getting this error.

Comment: Again: what is `connection`? Where do you define that class?

Comment: Please check this Link: [link](http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2014/03/connection-pool-in-java-jdbc.html)

Comment: Please let me know if still you have any question..

Comment: You still haven't answered: what is `connection`?

Comment: An empty array list to hold the connections

`public class JdbcConnectionPool {
 List<connection> availableConnections = new ArrayList<connection>();
}`

Actually I am trying to implement this code: [link](http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2014/03/connection-pool-in-java-jdbc.html)

Comment: You're not answering the question! You have to use your head and figure out what `connection` is. Don't just copy paste stuff from the Internet without understanding it. Think.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution.. :)

Comment: Don't implement your own connection pool, it is hard to do correctly, and it is a waste of time considering there are already libraries out there that do this. And they will likely do it better than your code will ever get. Your current code already shows things that will make it hard to use correctly, for example connection pools will generally proxy a connection and use `close()` to return it to the pool, yours would require a call to `returnConnectionToPool` which 1) is not common idiom and 2) will disallow use of libraries that will obtain and release a connection in their own code.

Comment: Also: why are you casting to a `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`, instead of just using `java.sql.Connection`, and then trying to store it in a list with an undefined type `connection`?